# How can I get a list of the user's recently and/or frequently opened files?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to get a list of the files which have been opened by the user a) recently and/or 
b) frequently.

Is this information available on Windows operating systems (Need support for everything down to XP) and if yes, is there a way to use this data with .NET Framework?

Searching the topic on Google is kind of hard, because the results are always referring to solutions where people want to achieve the same thing for their own application only (i.e. create a list of recently used files). I need the same thing on OS level, not just for files which have been opened with the appplication created by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution can be to use `Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent`:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent);
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path);
```

Note that this solution only lists the recent opened documents. If you want a better solution, you can take a look to this article about how to use the `Windows.Storage.AccessCache` API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh972344.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Windows' MRU List you can find it in Registry.

[This](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/List_of_Windows_MRU_Locations) link might help you alot.